# calling a HTTP get method to populate the result in drop down using angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have all controllers defined at one place.

```
 $routeProvider.when(pages.hello, 
    {
      templateUrl: 'test/hello.html', 
      controller: 'myController',
      access: access.anon,
      helloPage: 'arf'
    });
```

My hello.html looks like this.

```
<select name="chooseFunc" data-ng-model="choosenFunction"  class="input-xlarge ng-pristine ng-valid" data-ng-click="fetchID()"  data-ng-change="update(choosenFunction)">
            <option value="ABCD">ABCD</option>
            <option value="CDEF">CDEF</option>            
        </select>
```

Now I want to call a http get method "/abc/hello" to populate the drop down like ABCD, CDEF values based on it.

I have written some thing like this.

```
 $scope.fetchID = function() {
        console.log("hello in fectch id"); 
        $http.get('/abc/hello').success(successCallback).error(error);        
      };
```

My function is not getting called. Could some help me with the following.

1. Calling fecthID() function on page load.
2. fechID() function should populate the options in select element.

I am new here. Can some one help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write controller like:

```
function myController($scope,$http) {

    $scope.values = [{id:"ABCD",Name:"David"},{id:"CDEF",Name:"John"}];

    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.values[0].id;

     $scope.fetchID = function() {

        $http.get('/abc/hello').success(
            function(data, status, headers, config){
                $scope.values.push(data);// play here
            }) 
        .error(error);          
      };

 $scope.fetchID(); // call
}
```

and `hello.html` with init first combo value:

```
   <select name="chooseFunc"        
    ng-model="selectedItem"        
     ng-options="selectedItem.id as selectedItem.id for selectedItem in values"          
     class="input-xlarge ng-pristine ng-valid"          
     data-ng-click="fetchID()"          
      data-ng-change="update(choosenFunction)"          
      ></select>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. My JSON object will look like this. can you also tell me how do I achieve this.[{"id":"ABCD","Name":"David"},{"id":"CDEF","Name":"John"}]

And I want to display some thing like this
 <option value="ABCD">David</option>
 <option value="CDEF">John</option>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-options` to populate select like

```
<select ng-model="mySelecetdValue" ng-options="item for item in items">
</select>
```

To Call `fecthID()`, Just call it like

```
$scope.fetchID()
```

And Populate `items` in `successCallback` function

Comment: Thanks for replying. It would be great if you could also help me to call fetchID() function on page load and populate items.

Comment: @Patan, can you provide code for `successCallback `which you are using